# How to check if object exists in queue before pushing new object

Tags: python, queue, pydev

I'm using a Python queue:

```
q = Queue.Queue()
```

I'm putting objects of a certain class into the aforementioned queue using `q.put(item)`. However, before putting the item into the queue, I would like to check if it exists in the queue already. Is there a way to do this? [without taking out all of the objects of the queue and then pushing them all back in]

Additionally:

I don't know how I could actually see the variables I'm putting into the queue (when debugging). I'm using Pydev, and all I could see in the `variables` window is stuff like `not_empty` and `not_full`. How could I see what's in the queue during run time?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can treat 'q.queue' as a list.

```
if item in q.queue:
   print("already there!")
```

Comment: On python2.5 this causes `<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>:argument of type 'instance' is not iterable`

Comment: Does this not invite a race condition, between checking and printing/processing data

Comment: Sorry - for Python 3.6 the same error occurs -> TypeError: argument of type 'Queue' is not iterable

Comment: Note that `q` is an instance of the `queue.Queue` object, whereas `q.queue` is a `collections.deque` argument that allows iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can provide such mechanism to a class of your own.

```
class UniqueQueue:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__item_pool = []

    def push(self, item):
        if item not in self.__item_pool:
            self.__item_pool.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.__item_pool.pop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need `queue.Queue`? `queue.Queue` is a synchronised collection, and so offers more functionality than is needed in most cases.

You may want to look at using `queue.deque` or possibly using [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) to create your own `OrderedSet`.

eg.

```
q = queue.deque()
q.appendleft(1)
q.appendleft(2)
q.appendleft(3)
assert 2 in q
assert q.pop() == 1
```

In python 2, the `queue` module is called `Queue`.